# How can I change the text in the Wix installer dialog?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3

My text message is stuck to "Install My Product to:"
How can I change this?

("My Product" is the name of my product and the string above is resolved based on the Name attribute in my Product.wxs).

I have 2 dialogs and the second requires a different message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some text on the built-in dialogs can be changed with variables specified in the localization file for your language. This is a simpler task than if you are trying to change text that is not kept in a variable.
This process is documented [here](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/wixui/wixui_customizations.html).

However, if that's the case, the recommended way to change the dialog on the install page is to make a copy of and change the template file(s) provided with the WiX installation.

Copy the relevant .wxs files from your WiX dialog extension set (you will need to make sure you installed the WiX source) you want to modify and copy the file that specifies the UI extension name. Modify it to suit your needs and change the names.

When you compile your installer, you will use your new extension name (referring to your modified dialog set) and tell candle/light where your modified .wxs files are.
This process has some good documentation [here](http://neilsleightholm.blogspot.com/2008/08/customised-uis-for-wix.html) and [here](http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/tutorial/user-interface/new-link-in-the-chain).
Following the entire tutorial at the second link should get you pretty far.

Good luck

Comment: Thanks Ryan. I was tryting to apply the method in your first link but failed. I just wanted to change the text message, looks like its a bigger task than expected. I was told it would be a 5 minute task. Not so, I'll reschedule. Thanks.